# Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, reference, request.querystring

When I try to open the page from my IDE in VS 2008 using "VIEW IN BROWSER" option I get "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error.

The piece of code I get this error :

```
 XResult = Request.QueryString["res"];    
 TextBox1.Text = XResult.ToString();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem here is that `XResult` is `null` and when you call `ToString` on it the code produces a `NullReferenceException`.  You need to account for this by doing an explicit `null` check

```
TextBox1.Text = XResult == null ? String.empty : XResult.ToString();
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are opening the page without the "res" query string then you need to include a check for null before you do anything with it.

```
if (Request.QueryString["res"] != null)
{
    XResult = Request.QueryString["res"];
    TextBox1.Text = XResult.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That error could be Because the REquest.QueryString method did not find a value for "res" in the url so when you try to do the "toString" to a null object whrow that exeption.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is expecting a query string `http://localhost:xxxx/yourapp?res=yourval`. It's not present in the address supplied to the browser. In the *web* section of your project properties, you can supply an appropriate URL. Of course, shoring up your code to allow for this would be advisable.

Answer (score 0):

XResult is already a string, so calling ToString isn't necessary.  That should also fix your problem.

Comment: .ToString() on a string won't throw an error. The issue is that XResult is null because it's not finding "res" in the query string.

Comment: It is already a string and the call to `.ToString()` is not necessary, but it will not fix your problem.

Comment: It will solve the null reference exception, because calling .ToString() on a null will throw the exception.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that XResult is null, and when you call `ToString`
on it the code produces a `NullReferenceException`. You need to account for this by doing an explicit null check:

```
if (Request.QueryString["res"] != null)
{
    XResult = Request.QueryString["res"];
    TextBox1.Text = XResult.ToString();
}
```